# AudioKit: pan oscillator

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

How can I pan an oscillator to one ear using AudioKit? This is what I have right now:

```
oscillator = AKOscillator()
leftPan = AKPanner(oscillator, pan: -1)
mix = AKMixer(leftPan, oscillator)
AudioKit.output = mix
AudioKit.start()
mix.start()
leftPan.start()
oscillator.start()
```

However, the sound is still playing in both ears.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @Dopapp, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
oscillator.start()
leftPan = AKPanner(oscillator, pan: -1)
AudioKit.output = leftPan
AudioKit.start()
```

You seem to not even need the mixer. My guess is that it's redundant, which messes up the pan.

[Source.](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/issues/784)

Comment: I don't think you need leftPan.start() either, effects are on by default

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of the sound being in both ears is mixing the original oscillator, which is mono (not panned).  DopApps's answer is correct: simply assign "leftPan" to the AudioKit.output.